# How do i create a stock level report in magento?

Tags: magento2, inventory, sku, qty

I need to get a stock report from Magento.

what do we have in stock?

what SKUs - what Qty.

how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

On the Admin sidebar, go to Reports > Products > Low Stock.

The Low Stock Report lists all products with stock levels within a specified range. With Inventory Management enabled, the report includes low stock inventory amounts per source with the listed source code.